# Задание из книги по теме "Указатели" на С(Си)

Tags: c, указатели

Задание из книги K&R звучит следующим образом:

> Напишите функцию strend(s, t), которая выдает 1, если строка t расположена в конце строки s, и нуль в противном случае.

Вот мой вариант решения:

```
int strend(char *begin, char *end)
{
    char *temp = end;
    while(*begin++ != '\0')
    {
        while(*begin == *temp)
        {
            if(*begin++ == '\0' && *temp++ == '\0') 
                return 1;
            else
                temp = end;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Пытался в блоке else менять temp на *temp и различные другие вариации указателей, но если и получалось как-то отладить, программа все равно работала с багами.
Конкретно в таком виде она совсем не выполняет своей функции, хотя как по мне, логика верная. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: может проще пройти указателем до конца строки, а потом сверку делать в обратном порядке?

Comment: Используйте `strlen()` для поиска концов обеих строк. Затем сравнивайте (естественно, если `t` не длиннее `s`), начиная с последних символов каждой строки

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, да, длины строк вычислить хорошо, но движение вперёд эффективнее движения назад.

Comment: @avp, а зачем с последних, если можно с нужного места в прямом направлении?

Comment: @Qwertiy, даже не знаю, чего на меня нашло...(наверное предыдущий комментарий повлиял) Согласен, в общем случае (когда мы не знаем вероятности появления совпадающих символов в зависимости от смещения в строках) в прямом направлении (особенно, вызвав `memcmp()`) будет лучше.

Comment: @avp, о, точно. Заменил strcmp на memcmp в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//создаем нашу функцию str_B - наша строка , str_E - последняя строка
int strend(char *str_B,char *str_E);
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",strend("Example","le"));//вызываем
}

int strend(char *str_B,char *str_E)
{
    int count = 0;
    // находим разницу между длинами первой и второй строки,
    // а -1 для того чтобы правильно работала с индексами
    int dif = strlen(str_B) - strlen(str_E) - 1;
    for(int i = dif; i < strlen(str_B)-1;i++)// в нашем случаи ՝ от 4 до 7  
    {
        if(str_B[i+1] == str_E[count])// проверяем равны ли каждая "последняя" буква 
        {
            
        }else // а если нет то сразу возвращаем 0
        {
            return 0;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 1;// если все в порядке возвращаем 1 
}
```

Comment: Ну только strlen в условии цикла и не хватало...

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй, похожим решением будет такое (но оно неэффективное: O(n*m)): https://ideone.com/jjnsrT

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strend(const char *s, const char *t)
{
  for (const char *p, *u; ; ++s)
  {
    p = s;
    for (u=t; *u && *u==*p; ++u, ++p);
    if (!*p) return !*u;
  }
}

#define CHECK(s,t) printf("%-7s %-7s => %d\n", s, t, strend(s, t))

int main(void)
{
  CHECK("abc", "c");
  CHECK("a", "a");
  CHECK("a", "ab");
  CHECK("abc", "");
  CHECK("", "");
  CHECK("aaaaa", "aaab");
  CHECK("", "q");
  
  return 0;
}
```

```
abc     c       => 1
a       a       => 1
a       ab      => 0
abc             => 1
                => 1
aaaaa   aaab    => 0
        q       => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Самым эффективным будет такой вариант: <s>https://ideone.com/lVykU3</s> https://ideone.com/4P0jPf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>
 
int strend(const char *s, const char *t)
{
  size_t n = strlen(s), m = strlen(t);
  return n >= m && !memcmp(s+n-m, t, m);
}
 
#define CHECK(s,t) printf("%-7s %-7s => %d\n", s, t, strend(s, t))
 
int main(void)
{
  CHECK("abc", "c");
  CHECK("a", "a");
  CHECK("a", "ab");
  CHECK("abc", "");
  CHECK("", "");
  CHECK("aaaaa", "aaab");
  CHECK("", "q");
 
  return 0;
}
```

Либо, если не использовать стандартные функции: https://ideone.com/W8odK1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int strend(const char *s, const char *t)
{
  const char *p;
  size_t n, m;
 
  for (p=t; *p; ++p);
  m = p - t;
 
  for (p=s; *p; ++p);
  n = p - s;
 
  if (n < m)
    return 0;
 
  for (s += n - m; s != p; ++s, ++t)
    if (*s != *t)
      return 0;
 
  return 1;
}
 
#define CHECK(s,t) printf("%-7s %-7s => %d\n", s, t, strend(s, t))
 
int main(void)
{
  CHECK("abc", "c");
  CHECK("a", "a");
  CHECK("a", "ab");
  CHECK("abc", "");
  CHECK("", "");
  CHECK("aaaaa", "aaab");
  CHECK("", "q");
 
  return 0;
}
```

```
abc     c       => 1
a       a       => 1
a       ab      => 0
abc             => 1
                => 1
aaaaa   aaab    => 0
        q       => 0
```